# loose column when using .groupby() in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use the .groupby() function with panda dataframes, but I keep loosing the column that I am trying to group. 
I tried to group by the year and it succeeds in doing this but

the column name gets removes so I am unable to call the column. An extra row is added that has the column name, but I am unable to access it. 
Am I doing something wrong?

for example I ran the code below

```
stats2 = stats.groupby('yearID').mean()
```

and I get this as the result

```
              2B      3B                HR       BB       1B
yearID                  
1956    0.035939    0.007809    0.024694    0.096666    0.164637
1957    0.036462    0.007220    0.023651    0.087744    0.167484
1958    0.036856    0.007120    0.024353    0.088281    0.166760
```

any ideas on what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `as_index = False`, option when grouping

```
stats2 = stats.groupby('yearID', as_index = False).mean()
```

As the other user has made clear, the default behaviour is that the group key becomes the index. This behaviour is prevented by using the option just described.

Answer (score 1):

The column you group by becomes an index in the result. That's what you call the "extra column".

If you want to recover that as a column, you should `stats2.reset_index()`.